# Need to test remote mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, winforms, networking

Last week I updated a clients website - then several days later they phoned up telling me that their admin system has a connection problem.
( Error : Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts )

Their admin system is a winform application which connects remotely to a mysql database - and they somehow think its my fault... they are not technical and their IT guy quit 2-3 days before they starting having any issues.
The Website is working perfectly and i'm able to remote connect to the database and Admin program from my location - so everything is working perfectly for me.

So:

- I've checked the mysql user and privileges settings (managed via
  phpmyadmin) - their username and the allowed host/IP are correct.
- Their IP was aready whitelisted on the server.

I'm thinking that theres an internal firewall issue ( apparently they did have a firewall issue around the time this issue started ) but I need a way of testing/proving this.

( I'm a web developer not an network IT admin )

Comment: Just to test if it's a firewall issue, simply try connecting to the server from the terminal: http://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port

Comment: If it's on windows try [telnet](http://superuser.com/questions/339107/how-to-telnet-to-an-ip-address-on-a-specific-port)

Comment: They are running a windows system - I expect they will call me tomorrow so i'll try telnet. If there is a firewall issue what error message should i expect?

Comment: Probably just a timeout. If you do not get a timeout you could install somehting like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and see if that does connect.

Comment: Cheers - hopefully i can get this issue ironed out, its bugging the hell out of me! - if you can think of anything else let me know so i'm ready for that awkward call tomorrow morning :/

Comment: No problem, do you have acces to the server yourself or is it like passing commands over the phone?

Comment: Passing commands over the phone... - I do have root access to the server (debian)

Comment: Bummer, if telnet does connect you should check your log files. Good luck.